# SpringBoot and Spring Security not authenticate

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-boot

I created a SpringBoot application with basic security (User, Role) it works fine. After that I want extend the application with Permissions but now I stuck because my app not authenticate anymore.

I just added/modified the entities and services.

So when I tried to get this resource: `http://localhost:8080/user/list` the login page come in as I want, but when I type the user credentials I got an `AccessDenied exception` in this is happen with all resource witch is annotated with `@PreAuthorize`.

A controller sample:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {
    @RequestMapping("/user/list")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('PERM_READ_USER')")
    public String listUsers(Model model){
        return "user/list";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/user/show")
    public String getUser(){
        return "user/show";
    }
```

Debug info:

```
2016-09-08 16:10:06.458 DEBUG 22958 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/address/list]
2016-09-08 16:10:06.458 DEBUG 22958 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /address/list
2016-09-08 16:10:06.458 DEBUG 22958 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public java.lang.String com.example.controllers.AddressController.listAddresses()]
2016-09-08 16:10:06.459 DEBUG 22958 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/address/list] is: -1
2016-09-08 16:10:06.460 DEBUG 22958 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String com.example.controllers.AddressController.listAddresses()]: org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
2016-09-08 16:10:06.460 DEBUG 22958 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] .w.s.m.a.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String com.example.controllers.AddressController.listAddresses()]: org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
2016-09-08 16:10:06.460 DEBUG 22958 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String com.example.controllers.AddressController.listAddresses()]: org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
2016-09-08 16:10:06.465 DEBUG 22958 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Could not complete request

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:84) ~[spring-security-core-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:233) ~[spring-security-core-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:65) ~[spring-security-core-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at com.example.controllers.AddressController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d75cbf26.listAddresses(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) [spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:121) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:522) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_101]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_101]

2016-09-08 16:10:06.480 DEBUG 22958 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/login]
2016-09-08 16:10:06.480 DEBUG 22958 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /login
2016-09-08 16:10:06.480 DEBUG 22958 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public java.lang.String com.example.controllers.IndexController.loginForm()]
2016-09-08 16:10:06.480 DEBUG 22958 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/login] is: -1
2016-09-08 16:10:06.482 DEBUG 22958 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Requested media types are [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/webp, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8] based on Accept header types and producible media types [*/*])
2016-09-08 16:10:06.482 DEBUG 22958 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver  : No matching bean found for view name 'login'
2016-09-08 16:10:06.482 DEBUG 22958 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Returning [org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView@56f2df29] based on requested media type 'text/html'
2016-09-08 16:10:06.482 DEBUG 22958 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Rendering view [org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView@56f2df29] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2016-09-08 16:10:06.485 DEBUG 22958 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
2016-09-08 16:10:06.583 DEBUG 22958 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/webjars/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js]
2016-09-08 16:10:06.583 DEBUG 22958 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css]
2016-09-08 16:10:06.584 DEBUG 22958 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /webjars/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js
2016-09-08 16:10:06.584 DEBUG 22958 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /webjars/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css
2016-09-08 16:10:06.584 DEBUG 22958 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for [/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css]
2016-09-08 16:10:06.584 DEBUG 22958 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Matching patterns for request [/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css] are [/webjars/**, /**]
2016-09-08 16:10:06.584 DEBUG 22958 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : URI Template variables for request [/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css] are {}
2016-09-08 16:10:06.585 DEBUG 22958 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapping [/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[class path resource [META-INF/resources/webjars/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@2842c098]]] and 1 interceptor
2016-09-08 16:10:06.585 DEBUG 22958 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css] is: -1
2016-09-08 16:10:06.585 DEBUG 22958 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for [/webjars/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js]
2016-09-08 16:10:06.586 DEBUG 22958 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Matching patterns for request [/webjars/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js] are [/webjars/**, /**]
2016-09-08 16:10:06.586 DEBUG 22958 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : URI Template variables for request [/webjars/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js] are {}
2016-09-08 16:10:06.586 DEBUG 22958 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapping [/webjars/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[class path resource [META-INF/resources/webjars/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@2842c098]]] and 1 interceptor
2016-09-08 16:10:06.586 DEBUG 22958 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/webjars/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js] is: -1
2016-09-08 16:10:06.589 DEBUG 22958 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2016-09-08 16:10:06.589 DEBUG 22958 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
2016-09-08 16:10:06.595 DEBUG 22958 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2016-09-08 16:10:06.597 DEBUG 22958 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
```

But when I just simply call `/login` and I type the credentials and click to submit nothing happen.

I get this debug info in this case:

```
2016-09-08 16:16:29.567 DEBUG 22958 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing POST request for [/login]
2016-09-08 16:16:29.570 DEBUG 22958 --- [io-8080-exec-10] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /login
2016-09-08 16:16:29.570 DEBUG 22958 --- [io-8080-exec-10] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public java.lang.String com.example.controllers.IndexController.loginForm()]
2016-09-08 16:16:29.571 DEBUG 22958 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.web.cors.DefaultCorsProcessor        : Skip CORS processing: request is from same origin
2016-09-08 16:16:29.572 DEBUG 22958 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Requested media types are [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/webp, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8] based on Accept header types and producible media types [*/*])
2016-09-08 16:16:29.572 DEBUG 22958 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.w.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver  : No matching bean found for view name 'login'
2016-09-08 16:16:29.572 DEBUG 22958 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Returning [org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView@56f2df29] based on requested media type 'text/html'
2016-09-08 16:16:29.572 DEBUG 22958 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Rendering view [org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView@56f2df29] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2016-09-08 16:16:29.576 DEBUG 22958 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
2016-09-08 16:16:29.659 DEBUG 22958 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/webjars/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js]
2016-09-08 16:16:29.659 DEBUG 22958 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /webjars/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js
2016-09-08 16:16:29.660 DEBUG 22958 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for [/webjars/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js]
2016-09-08 16:16:29.660 DEBUG 22958 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Matching patterns for request [/webjars/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js] are [/webjars/**, /**]
2016-09-08 16:16:29.660 DEBUG 22958 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : URI Template variables for request [/webjars/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js] are {}
2016-09-08 16:16:29.660 DEBUG 22958 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapping [/webjars/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[class path resource [META-INF/resources/webjars/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@2842c098]]] and 1 interceptor
2016-09-08 16:16:29.660 DEBUG 22958 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/webjars/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js] is: -1
2016-09-08 16:16:29.666 DEBUG 22958 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css]
2016-09-08 16:16:29.667 DEBUG 22958 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /webjars/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css
2016-09-08 16:16:29.668 DEBUG 22958 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2016-09-08 16:16:29.668 DEBUG 22958 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
2016-09-08 16:16:29.668 DEBUG 22958 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for [/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css]
2016-09-08 16:16:29.668 DEBUG 22958 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Matching patterns for request [/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css] are [/webjars/**, /**]
2016-09-08 16:16:29.668 DEBUG 22958 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : URI Template variables for request [/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css] are {}
2016-09-08 16:16:29.668 DEBUG 22958 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapping [/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[class path resource [META-INF/resources/webjars/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@2842c098]]] and 1 interceptor
2016-09-08 16:16:29.669 DEBUG 22958 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css] is: -1
2016-09-08 16:16:29.671 DEBUG 22958 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2016-09-08 16:16:29.671 DEBUG 22958 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
```

My userDetailsService:

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class SpringSecurityUserdetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    private UserService userService;
    private Converter<User, UserDetails> userToUserDetailsConverter;

    @Autowired
    public void setUserService(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "userToUserDetails")
    public void setUserUserDetailsConverter(Converter<User, UserDetails> userUserDetailsConverter) {
        this.userToUserDetailsConverter = userUserDetailsConverter;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return userToUserDetailsConverter.convert(userService.findByUsername(username));
    }
}
```

My security configuration:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity.csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/h2-console").disable()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**/favicon.ico") .permitAll()
            .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/webjars/**").permitAll()
            .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/static/css").permitAll()
            .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/js").permitAll()
            .and().formLogin().loginPage("/").permitAll()
            .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/access_denied");
}
```

My project also available in https://github.com/eszikk/spring-security/tree/spring-security-database-permissions . If you have any idea please let me know. Br,

Answer (score 2):

The request never reaches your controller, because you've not allowed this route in your security configuration.

You should add either:

```
.antMatchers("/user/**").hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
```

-or-

```
.antMatchers("/user/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
```

(mind the 'ROLE_' prefix in both cases).

Alternatively, you could add a global

```
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
```

matcher to allow access to any urls for any authenticated user. Then you could make use of the @PreAuthorize logic in your controllers to fine-tune access.

Also the '.authorizeRequests()' call allows chaining, which means you could do:

```
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**/favicon.ico") .permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/webjars/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/static/css").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/js").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion I modified the security config but still not working. I think the problem is related to the authentication instead of authorization. Thank for your answer.